# Images instead of links in search navigation

Tags: 2013, search, navigation

I am using SharePoint 2013 and I want to show images or icons instead of the default links in the Search Navigation.

Any tutorials or ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to a content editor webpart in the page where you have the search navigation. Modify the classes and code as needed,

```
 <style type='text/css'>     
     .nav1{
        background-image: url('image url goes here'); 
     }
     .nav2{
        background-image: url('image url goes here');
     }
     .custom-search-nav{    
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 50px;
        height: 40px;
        display: block;
        background-size: contain;
     }
 </style>

 <script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
 <script type='text/javascript'>     
 $(document).ready(function(){      

    var navTags = $("ul[class='ms-srchnav-list'] a");       
    navTags.each(function(){
        var navText = $(this).text();
        if(navText === 'Everything'){
            addImageBackground($(this), 'nav1');
        }
        else if(navText === 'People'){
            addImageBackground($(this), 'nav2');            
        }
    });     

    function addImageBackground(aTag, className){
        aTag.addClass(className);
        aTag.addClass('custom-search-nav');
        aTag.text('');
    }
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: The answer solved my problem. However I check the HTML code of the page and It seems that each item of the nav does not have an "id" (I suppose this is the reason the previous answer uses "Text" instead).   Is It a better way to select each item of the nav than its "Text" (to avoid problems if renaming, etc.)?

Comment: The other option would be to use the order of the nav items. In the each loop have an index and use the index value to call and pass parameters to the addImageBackground method. But then you would run into problems if you change the order of the nav items anytime.